# Equivalences between closed sets in metric spaces

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, elementary-set-theory, metric-spaces

Are these statements equivalents: a),b) with 1)    ?

a) $B$ is closed in $A$.

b) If $(x_n)_n$ is any sequence of points of $B$ such that $ x_n\to a$ and $a \in A$, then $a \in B$.

1) $B$ is closed if and only if it contains all it's limit points.

Comment: And what's your definition of limit points? I suppose 1) is your definition of closed.

Comment: No, the definition of closed is : A is closed iff $ \ A^c $ is open. And the definition of limit point is: for all $ \mathcal E $ there is a point y $ \in $ B such that d(x,y)< $ \mathcal E $.

Comment: My intuition says that indeed those statements are the 'same', but I want to be sure, so I need the opinion of the experts :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, they are equivalent in metric spaces:

Supppose $B$ is closed. (so $B^c$ is open)

Suppose that $x$ is a limit point of $B$. If $x \notin B$, then $x \in B^c$ and by openness of the later set, there is some $\varepsilon >0$, such that $B(x,\varepsilon) \subset B^c$. This means that any point $y$ with $d(x,y) < \varepsilon$ lies not in $B$,
but this means that $x$ cannot be a limit point of $B$. Contradiction, so $x \in B$ and $B$ contains all its limit points.

Now suppose $B$ contains all its limit points, and we have $b_n \to x$,where all $b_n \in B$. Then $x$ is a limit point of $B$ (for any $\varepsilon >0$ the ball $B(x,\varepsilon)$ will contain all $b_n$ for $ n \ge N$ for some $N$, from the definition of convergence, so in particular for every $\varepsilon > 0$ there is some $b_N \in B$ with $d(x,b_N) < \varepsilon$), and so by assumption on $B$, $x \in B$. So $B$ is closed under limits of sequences.

Suppose $B$ is closed under limits of sequences,and suppose that $B$ is not closed. This means that $B^c$ is not open, so there is a point $x \in B^c$ that is not an interior point of $B^c$. The latter means that $B^c$ cannot completely contain any $\varepsilon$-ball around $x$, so for every $\varepsilon >0$: $B(x,\varepsilon) \cap B \neq \emptyset$. Now take for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$ $\varepsilon = \frac{1}{n} > 0$ and pick $b_n \in B(x,\frac{1}{n}) \cap B$. Claim: $b_n \to x$: so pick $\varepsilon > 0$. Pick $N$ so large that $\frac{1}{N} < \varepsilon$; then for all $n \ge N$: $\frac{1}{n} \le \frac{1}{N}$ so $b_n \in B(x, \frac{1}{n}) \subseteq B(x, \frac{1}{N}) \subseteq B(x,\varepsilon)$, which means that for all $n \ge N$: $d(b_n, x) < \varepsilon$ as required. As $B$ was assumed to be closed under limits of sequences we conclude that $x \in B$, contradiction, as $x \in B^c$ by choice.

So we closed the loop and all versions (complement open, closed under limit points, closed under sequence limits) are equivalent.

Only the last part really used the metric, or at least that every point has a countable decreasing base of neighbourhoods (like the $B(x, \frac{1}{n})$) to be able to construct sequences like we did. The rest of the implications hold in all topological spaces (replacing open balls by open sets).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your first two statements are (namely a, and b) are equivalent. These statements also cover the *relative* case. 
Statement 1 is valid only in the absolute case. If $B$ is contained in the ambient space $A$ then you may give this as the definition of a closed set. Yet, equip the real line $\mathbf{R}$ with the standard metric (induced from the absolute value) and say $A = [0,1)$, $B = [\frac{1}{2},1)$. Then, $B$ is closed in $A$ but not closed in $\mathbf{R}$.
Bottom line: no, one needs a minor modification in statement 1:
$B$ is closed in $A$ if and only if it contains all it's limit points that are in $A$.